# How to write exactly <h2> in html?

Tags: html, escaping, html-escape-characters

I would like to know how to write EXACTLY `<h2>` in HTML? Because every time I write `<h2>` in HTML it acts as an element. But I want `<h2>` as it is on my website.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. its absolutely unclear what you're asking.

Comment: do you mean like this `&lt;h2&gt;` https://jsfiddle.net/am8qfue6/

Comment: i want to write <h2> in my webpage. Like as-it-is word to word , but everytime i write <h2> in my html code it acts as an element.

Comment: **look at https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref to find any charactere entity html**  ;) There was also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp that is if you  want to take a chance to make a full mess of your html page.

Comment: there are special codes for some "Character Entity" .. this chart may help you https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Answer (score 3):

I presume you want to write `<h2>` in HTML.

See, h2 in Stackoverflow (Stackoverflow renders some html tags, h2 included): <h2> actual text: `&lt;h2&gt;`

`&lt;` is the less than symbol escaped
`&gt;` is the greater than symbol escaped

`&lt; &gt;` in html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Show H2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>&lt;h2&gt;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes thank you. God I'm so stupid.

Comment: @Kritika no worries, happy you got it solved. If my answer helped you, please click the checkmark

Answer (score 1):

To output the H2 without parsing as a tag. You would use like below..

```
 &lt;h2&gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show HTML code on your website, you have to escape the less-than and greater-than symbols. E.g:

```
&lt;H2&gt;
```

`&lt;` is the escaped version of '<'. And `&gt;` is the escaped version of '>'.